# Evernote bootstrap doesn't work in Evernote China Yinxiang Biji

Tags: ios, evernote

I want to support Evernote China with their iOS SDK.
https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios

Evernote says it will switch to Evernote China automatically with their bootstrap system, but my below swift code in AppDelegate doesn't work in Evernote China, is there anything wrong?
https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/bootstrap.php

```
// Works without China
ENSession.setSharedSessionConsumerKey(Key.Evernote.cunsumerKey,
consumerSecret: Key.Evernote.cunsumerSecret,
optionalHost: nil)

// Doesn't work anywhere
ENSession.setSharedSessionConsumerKey(Key.Evernote.cunsumerKey,
consumerSecret: Key.Evernote.cunsumerSecret,
optionalHost: ENBootstrapProfileNameInternational)

// Doesn't work anywhere
ENSession.setSharedSessionConsumerKey(Key.Evernote.cunsumerKey,
consumerSecret: Key.Evernote.cunsumerSecret,
optionalHost: ENBootstrapProfileNameChina)

// Doesn't work anywhere
ENSession.setSharedSessionConsumerKey(Key.Evernote.cunsumerKey,
consumerSecret: Key.Evernote.cunsumerSecret,
optionalHost: "www.evernote.com")
```

Comment: Evernote China is now a standalone service and bootstrapping should not be used in new integrations, see note at top of https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/bootstrap.php

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I didn't notice that.